# Vagrant + Virtual Box - Virtual host not accessible

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Vagrant set up on my machine which uses Virtual Box. When I start Vagrant and ssh into it, the Virtual Box VM starts up. I can ping the server. But I cannot access the url I set in the hosts file via my browser. I've removed the browser's proxy as well.

Any step that I need to do to get it running?

Note: I'm on Windows 7, using Vagrant 1.5.1 and VirtualBox 4.3.8.

Comment: Do you have a virtual host setup in the virtual machine?

Comment: What webserver did you install? What configuration? What's the error message?

Comment: I'm very new to Vagrant. @Sgoettschkes The server is Apache. What do you exactly mean by configuration? No errors, just that the page doesn't load up in the browser. I would like to know where can I see the log.

Comment: @JeremyQuinton Virtual host as in? From what I read, Vagrant does it all for VirtualBox, I just need to update my hosts file to point to the IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the server on the IP and port that you've setup your webserver, very likely the issue is with your webserver's config and how it responds to external IPs

As an example, installing Apache on the precise image requires you to 'listen all'